# Div get overflow scroll when using css-grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I´m using css-grid and haven´t hade a problem whit it until now. I´m usually pretty good whit css but can´t figure out what the problem is.

```
<div class="the_grid">
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
  <div>Some content</div>
</div>

...

.the_grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: auto;
   grid-gap: 2%;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

The last part in the grid is not showen if I don´t scroll, I can add some padding at the bottom and the scroll is removed but that´s not a solution that I think is going to work in the long run because the content differ from person to person. The content in the div´s are different length but I haven´t hade the same problem before and have been using grid in a few projects now. I tried adding 100% height, and same on the surrounding div´s as well but it dosen´t make any difference.

EDIT:

I got the answer below, it was the %, I changed it to rem and i worked.

Comment: Sounds like the container is overflowing. I think we need some more code to be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Yep Joe, just to little code look at and get you going again, post a [reprex]

Answer (score 0):

Issue with `grid-gap: 2%;` precisely the percentage value.

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#propdef-row-gap)

> percentages resolve against zero for determining intrinsic size contributions, but resolve against the box’s content box when laying out the box’s contents.

Which means percentages will wait until the content has been laid out, get the width/height of the parent, calculate then add the space between grid items, Which causes overflow.

**Demo**

```css
body * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.the_grid {
  background: red;
  /* inline for side-by-side comparison */
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

/* same for grid-columns-gap, for the sake of this demo i only used row */
.gap {
  grid-row-gap: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="the_grid">
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
</div>

<div class="the_grid gap">
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
</div>
```

---

**Solution**

Don't use percentage values.

```css
body * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.the_grid {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="the_grid">
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>Some</div>
</div>
```

You should simply avoid using percentages in grid as they are unpredictable, [Good Read](https://blogs.igalia.com/mrego/2018/08/10/changes-on-css-grid-layout-in-percentages-and-indefinite-height/)